# How to measure the mass of a probability distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

If I generate a Normal and leptokurtotic continuous probability distribution (pdf), how can I measure the **mass** of these pdf's?

If both pdf's have the same number of sample observations, but obviously have different statistical moments, can we expect that the area/mass that these two distributions enclose be different or identical to one another?

How does the concept of **pdf mass** compare to the concepts and estimation of pdf **moments** and **shape**?

Comment: A probability distribution always have total mass 1. The mass is defined as the sum (or integral in continuous) of probabilities over the whole space and by definition of proba, it is 1. For a random variable $X$, the moments are the mean of $X$, the mean of $X^2$, the mean of $X^3$... I am not sure what you are refering to when talking of shape.

Comment: Are you looking for the *support* of a distribution?